# Problems with data transfer between c# client and node.js server

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, server, transfer

I am writing a chat, having a node.js server and some c# clients, with pooling (a request every 10 sec) -- using a Backgroundworker, nothing special.
But it turned out to be a bit disturbing, as I **am able** to send data from the client to the server on the one hand, but am still **not able** to send the message from the server back to the client.

Here is my server so far:

```
 var http = require("http");
var qs = require("querystring");
var fileSystem = require("fs");
var portNr = 81;
http.createServer(onRequest).listen(portNr, onready);
var feld = [];


function onRequest(request, response) {
   var body = "";
   var obj = {
       msg:"df",
       sentby:"df"
   };


   request.on("data", function(data) {
        if(data!=""){
            obj = JSON.parse(data);

        }
   });
   request.on("end", function() {
       if(undefined!=obj) //as there are requests every 10 seconds {
           response.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
           console.log(obj.msg);
           response.write(obj.msg);
           response.end();
         }
       else //send nothing back if nothing was requested
        response.end();
   });


}
function onready() {

    console.log("Server laeuft");
}
```

and here is my c# client, first my pooling method :

```
public void Pooling(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            while (run)
            {
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:81");
                request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
               WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
               Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
               StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);


               string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

               //Message n = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Message>(responseFromServer);
               reader.Close();
               response.Close();

               Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate()
               {
                   if (responseFromServer != "")
                   {
                       this.listbox.Items.Add(responseFromServer);
                       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                   }
                });
              }

        }
```

and now my method which will be executed when the 'send' button is clicked:

```
 var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:81");
           MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream();
           StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream1);
           Message = new Message(this.msg.Text, this.sentby.Text);


           System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Message));
           ser.WriteObject(stream1, n);
           stream1.Position = 0;

           string hilf = sr.ReadToEnd();
           var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(hilf);

           request.Method = "POST";
           request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
           request.ContentLength = data.Length;

           using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
           {
               stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
           }


       }
```

You may have noticed I am using Json.
I can display the sent messages in the node.js server but he does net add that to the listbox in the c# client !!
Please anyone ? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I'm surprised your `JSON.parse()` does not throw: `data` event can fire multiple times with small chunks of incomplete data. Consider using an established framework ([`express`](https://github.com/strongloop/express/)) to prevent errors such as those.

Comment: seconding @zlumer advice, don't reinvent the wheel and waste time on weird bugs, get a well tested, extremely intensively used framework like `express` or `hapi` to do the heavy lifting for you, instead.